# Dynamic styleUrls in angular 2?

Tags: css, angular

Is it possible to dynamically inject urls to stylesheets into a component?

Something like:

```
styleUrls: [
  'stylesheet1.css',
  this.additionalUrls
]
```

or (wishful thinking and note that this is just fake code):

```
export class MyComponent implements dynamicUrls {

  ngDynamicUrls() {
    this.inject(['anotherStylesheet.css', 'anotherStylesheet2.css']);
  }
}
```

Because if you're gonna be able to override certain styles from `stylesheet1` without having access to it, how are you supposed to do that? My only idea is to have dynamic `styleUrls` somehow but I don't think this is even possible from what I could find.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

It's possible in some maybe hack way it worked for me. You can manipulate Angular 2 Component decorator, create your own and return Angular's decorator with your properties.

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    export interface IComponent {
      selector: string;
      template?: string;
      templateUrl?: string;
      styles?: string[];
      styleUrls?: string[];
      directives?: any;
      providers?: any;
      encapsulation?: number;
    }

    export function CustomComponent( properties: IComponent): Function {
      let aditionalStyles: string;

      try {
          aditionalStyles =  require(`path to aditional styles/${ properties.selector }/style/${        properties.selector }.${ GAME }.scss`);
          properties.styles.push(aditionalStyles);
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn(err)
        }
      }

      return Component( properties );
    }
```

And in your component replace default angular 2 @Component with new one.

```
import { CustomComponent } from 'path to CustomComponent';

@CustomComponent({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './template/home.template.html',
  styleUrls: [ './style/home.style.scss']
})
export class ......
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes this works fine for me. I'm using webpack and Angular 2.0.0

Comment: So @Chrillewoodz did you try it too? Thinking of using this implementation but might just create a new component for each style and reference the same templateUrl and import all the script from a 3rd module...

Comment: yeah but you still need to create a component pre style that needs to be used, it's not one component  that receives a style name from the server for instance, not really dynamic

Comment: you put there an extra bracket and that GAME var which is not declared !

Answer (score 7):

I have found a solution:
1. I have changed the styleurls to styles in the component decorator.
2. I will get my variable.
3. I will use the require command in my decorator.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
let lang = environment['lang'];

@Component({
   selector: 'app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styles: [require('./app.component.css'), require('./app.component.' + lang + '.css')]
  })

  export class AppComponent {

   constructor() { }

  }
```

In this basic example I have imported the environment variable and changed the css string dynamically.

Comment: This is my first answer is stackoverflow. I don't understand why the answer is not  good. Can you please explain? @Jean-FrançoisCorbett

Comment: I apologize! That comment & flag were meant for another answer, and apparently I somehow put them here. Please disregard! Your answer is just fine!  I'm not sure where I was looking. Apologies again.

Comment: @noahlubko Have you tried it with production? I don't think it will work with AOT compiler.

Comment: This definitely does not work with the `require` one step removed.  I made a module with a base component class, and it also includes `export const BASE_COMPONENT_STYLE = require("./base.component.css")`.  If I try to make a subclass with `styles: [BASE_COMPONENT_STYLE]`, Ivy complains with "Unable to evaluate this expression statically" -- it isn't able to resolve the CSS *during compilation*.

Comment: Did it here but I'm getting the following error: styleUrls must be an array of strings. Any suggestions my friends?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same need to dynamically inject urls to stylesheets and eventually ended to initialize a component for each variable css (in my case 3 differents styles) with empty template and use them in my app component with ngIf condition.

Thanks to the use of property "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None", the style of the selected component is then added to the header of the page and enable to get the correct renderer for the whole page.

Comment: The problem with this approach, is that the styles that Angular adds to the head, are not automatically removed when the component is destroyed.

Comment: They never are. Angular doesn't remove styles, ever.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have dynamic stylesheet URLs, because you cannot access your class property or method inside `@Component` decorator.

But you can achieve your goal by having dynamic style classes in your template.

Comment: Problem is that I won't have access to the templates, only to the components themselves.

Comment: Well, if you can't access the template & still want to have different styles, why not consider making different components with the same template (with different style sheets) & load the components dynamically.

Comment: That would be an option, but it still doesn't provide full personal customizing. Seems like such a functional hole that them really need to address..

Comment: Dynamic style classes means css overhead instead of taking advantage of sass variables. For each new skin you will be repeating the entire stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

I used the stylesheet link in the html template with ngIf condition, it worked for me.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="/stylesheets/classicTheme.css" *ngIf="theme === 'classic' " />
<link rel='stylesheet' href="/stylesheets/styleTheme.css" *ngIf="theme === 'style' " />
```

Comment: Just curious how this can actually work? with Angular 2, the "app" runs inside the _root_ element (usually lives under `<body>`). So, how can your code bind to the `theme` variable?

Comment: does not override styles for components

Comment: Not saying it will or won't work, but while everyone is thinking his won't work because of where the app runs, the app can change the page title, right? There must be _some_ access to the `<head>` section.