# How to change app wide css in Angular 2?

Tags: css, angular, stylesheet, angular2-template, angular2-directives

In my application I have different CSS file like fire.css, lake.css each giving different look to complete application.

Currently, I implemented with only 1 file main.css and added this file to 
**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/main.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/themes.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/common.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/plugins.css">
```

Now I wanted to change this dynamically as user select from the drop-down list.

My Idea:
Copy all css files to app folder and add themes there. 
Folder structure is

app
|-----app.component.ts
|-----app.routes.ts
|-----main.css
|-----lake.css
|-----Login
|-----Other Components...

I added css to styleUrls in **app.components.ts** App component now is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({

    selector: 'workshop-app',    
    template: `
        <body>
           <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       </body>
    `,
    directives : [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
    styleUrls : ['app/lake.css']
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Contents from Lake.css file is added to style tag under but not making changes in the app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36566111/2703334 maybe this would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

add this to the app.component.html

```
<head>
<link id="theme" rel='stylesheet' href='demo.css'>    
</head>
```

add this to app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';    
constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'demo2.css');
}
```

Comment: Good answer !!! Project is submitted without this feature I will try it in spare time.

Comment: happy to help you, wish you luck

Answer (score -1):

Use fileReplacements in Angular.json file:

```
"configurations": {
  "yourproject": { ... },
  "staging": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/styles.css",
        "with": "src/new-styles.css"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can check the usage better here: https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: he is asking to change styles dinamically when the user inputs some actions, not in build time