# Equivalent of $('link').each in Angular/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm attempting to replace `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/`... with `<link href='http://fonts.useso.com/`... for my users in China for an Angular (currently) 6 application. There is [an excellent article](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/google-fonts-china/) describing how to do so in JavaScript, but I don't know enough to come up with the equivalent in Angular. I considered `ViewChild` but it seems that only gives you child components of a component. Here's the function in JavaScript:

```
function replaceGoogleCDN() {
  $('link').each(function(){
    var $intial  = $(this).attr('href'),
        $replace = $intial.replace('//fonts.googleapis.com/', '//fonts.useso.com/');
        $(this).attr('href', $replace);
  });
}
```

and here are a few lines from the `index.html` with the two links that I need to change:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  ...
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root>
...
```

How do I do this in Angular?

Comment: So how to change jQuery to be plain JavaScript DOM? querySelectorAll and forEach

Comment: would this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794824/how-to-change-app-wide-css-in-angular-2