# Angular 5 apply stylesheets programmatically

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, angular-cli

Is there a way to apply SASS stylesheets to an Angular 5 project conditionally.

For example, in my app.component.ts file I can set a variable `theme = blue` or `theme = green` and somehow tell Angular to use a different color scheme for the application?

I have been trying to figure out a way to do this for a long time. Does anyone have any ideas? Currently, I set the stylesheets in the Angular Cli config.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531486/dynamic-styleurls-in-angular-2#39755547

Comment: You could have a class toggled dynamically on your root component or body, and have scss themes defined based on that class