# How to load Rtl/Ltr css conditionally in a Components styleUrls attribute

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

What is the correct way to load css files conditionally into a Component in angular 4+ ?

```
@Component({...
    styleUrls:['./rtl.css','./ltr.css']...
})
```

In my case I need to load Rtl/Ltr css conditionally depending on a param provided by a service (here called _translateService).

```
this._translateService.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {this.lang = event});
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531486/dynamic-styleurls-in-angular-2

Comment: The post you gave is good, BUT... its not the angular way.
Angular does not provide a way to load component css scripts dynamically? how come?