# dynamic styleUrls in angular 7

Tags: angular

After trying the other answers in SO, and none of them working, i'm thinking it a problem in the latest version of Angular...

This **will work**:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-some-thing',
    templateUrl: './some-thing.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./some-thing.component.scss', `./some-thing.component.extra.scss`]
})
```

Where as, this **will not**

```
const dynamic = 'extra';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-some-thing',
    templateUrl: './some-thing.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./some-thing.component.scss', `./some-thing.component.${dynamic}.scss`]
})
```

I assume it's down to some kind of runtime error? Does anyone have a solution for this? 'dynamic' will be populated from environment variables in the app.

thanks in advance!

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52054181/9217586

Comment: @Lys i tried that already. It just prints the file name, no scss comes into the build.

Comment: @Lys revisited that idea of using require, i was missing default. i have answered my own question. Thanks for the push back to that direction though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave this here for others:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-some-thing',
    templateUrl: './some-thing.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        require('./some-thing.component.scss').default,
        require(`./some-thing.component.${dynamic}.scss).default`
    ]
```

Notice, the '**.default**' added to the require. I had issues until I added default... lack of sleep i guess.

Comment: I know that post is old, but could You please add some more explanation how You did it? When I copy it, it seems to not work...

Comment: @ruddnisrus - This was so long ago I no longer have the code as on a different contract. What have you tried? Make a new post with your code etc, might be able to help aways

Comment: I'm getting this error styleUrls must be an array of strings ... why?

Comment: @Andre you will need to post code for us to see. Also keep in mind this was 3 years ago, lots has changed in Angular since then, so may need a different solution.